# Haskell regex behaves unexpectedly

Tags: regex, haskell

At first I should say that my regex knowlege is https://regex101.com - compilant. I don't know if I'm getting wrong the haskell part or the regex part:

I'm trying to use regex to match out domain of a website (stackoverflow.com out of meta.stackoverflow.com). For demo, I'm using simple regex "[\w]+.[\w]+$" which behaves correctly at https://regex101.com. However, in haskell:

```
λ> import qualified Text.Regex.TDFA as RX
λ> "google.com" RX.=~ "[\\w]+\\.[\\w]+$" :: String
""
λ> "google.com" RX.=~ "[\\w]+\\.[\\w]+$" :: Bool
False
```

What is causing this behavior and how can I fix it?

GHCI version is 7.10.3,
regex-tdfa version is 1.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but `\w` seems to be not supported by tdfa. When I used `[A-Za-z0-9]`, the output is correct

```
Prelude RX> "google.com" RX.=~ "[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$" :: Bool
True
```

`\\w` is treated as character `w` literally `\\d` is treated as character `d` literally.

Following are notations that can be used for this package (typical DFA engine behavior. *NOTE* :- This engine is also DFA based)

```
[[:digit:]] - Digits ([0-9])
[[:alpha:]] - Alphabets ([A-Za-z])
[[:alnum:]] - Alphanumeric ([A-Za-z0-9])
```

So, you can also use

```
Prelude RX> "www.www" RX.=~ "[[:alnum:]]+\\.[[:alnum:]]+$" :: Bool
True
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as expected. Is there a library that supports `\w`?

Comment: @Kiraa well I am not right one to answer this because I know nothing about haskell.. I answered it just for sake of regex..

Answer (score 3):

I believe that package uses POSIX Extended Regular expressions. Which means, like rock321987 observes, that `\w` or `\d` sequences used in perl/pcre [are not supported](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), and functionality relative to today's powerful regex engines is very limited.

Posix ERE does provide some [built-in, weird looking character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), like `[:alnum:]` which is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

It's hard to find truly concise information, but to sum up the information presented [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), this is what you get with POSIX ERE:

- character classes, more or less, using `[]` brackets including the 12 built-ins like `[:alnum:]` (alphanumerics) and `[:alpha:]` (alphabet letters)
- dot `.` - matches anything
- start and end of string anchors `^` and `$`
- star `*` - repeat preceding zero or more times
- The quantifiers `?`, `+`, `{n}`, `{n,m}` and`{n,}` - repeat the
  preceding token zero or once, once or more, n times, between n and m
  times, and n or more times, respectively
- alternation with the pipe `|`

...and that's basically it.