# Extracting body from HTML with Haskell

Tags: html, regex, haskell

Haskell beginner over here!

I'm trying to parse an [HTML String](https://github.com/Raychani1/Functional-Programming-Project/commit/8e8f2e2c3794e82da2a002fa8178d29f49116db4) and extract the body from it. I'm using GHC Version 9.0.2 . I've tried to extract it using Regex. I'm using **Text.Regex.TDFA** (Version 1.3.1.2). I've checked the functionality of my Regex at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/9Ur4Lc/1). Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959605/haskell-regex-behaves-unexpectedly) I've modified it to be in line with POSIX Extended Regular Expressions. But for some reason [my code](https://github.com/Raychani1/Functional-Programming-Project/commit/a5a83737b7c5caf17cbe5b4a2b826a453b129876) ( line 51 ) is still unable to match the body of the HTML.

So my question is why exactly is this happening and how to fix it? Or is there a better / easier way of HTML body extraction?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please *don't* use regexes to parse HTML: HTML is context-free language, so it requires a parser, not a regex (lexer). You can use [`scalpel`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scalpel) for effective HTML extraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do *not* capture HTML with a regex. HTML is a [*context-free language* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language), a regex can (often) only parser [*regular languages* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) and thus can not capture HTML. Even if for a (very) specific problem, it can be done with a regex, it will result in a cumbersome regex that is hard to write, validate, and bugfix.

Haskell has a library named [**`scalpel`** <sup>[hackage]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scalpel) which is quite effective in parsing HTML. You can for example extract the HTML in the `<body>` tag with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Text.HTML.Scalpel(innerHTML, scrapeStringLike)

scrapeStringLike myHtml (innerHTML "body")
```

with `myHtml` the string that contains the HTML of the page. Likely you want to more advanced scraping and `scalpel` allows to define a hierarchy of scrapers that each perform a small task to construct an andvanced parser.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

- `<body.*>` is too greedy
- `([\w|\W])` no need for pipe inside of a char set and it's missing a quantifier
- `<\/body>` is fine

---

You need this:

```regex
<body.*?>([\w\W]*)<\/body>
```

https://regex101.com/r/9rVCUQ/1

---

Everyone is going to want to tell you that you shouldn't parse/extract html using regex. Use an html parsing library for more reliable results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried it, but unfortunately it throws me the following error : `unexpected '?' expecting empty () or anchor ^ or $, an atom, "|" or end of input`

Comment: @Raychani1 Sounds like Haskell is having an issue with the lazy quantifier `.*?`. You could try [`<body[^>]*>([\w\W]*)<\/body>`](https://regex101.com/r/F4JpSt/1) instead.

Comment: I've tried it and even with the POSIX ERE equivalent version of it (  
`[[:word:]]` and `[^[:word:]]` ), but it still returns an empty String.